# Using version as a partial primary key, how to get latest version of an entity given its id?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a REST API backed by a MySQL DB with multiple entity types, all of which have a composite primary key:

```
@Embeddable
public class EntityId {
    private int id;
    private int version;
}
```

For an endpoint such as /bananas I'd like to return the latest version of each banana. I'm able to return all versions of all bananas given the following:

```
("SELECT b FROM BananaEntity b").getResultList();
```

Which yields:

```
[
  {
    entityId: {
      id: 1,
      version: 1
    },
    name: "Banana A"
  },
  {
    entityId: {
      id: 1,
      version: 2
    },
    name: "Banana A"
  },
  {
    entityId: {
      id: 1,
      version: 3
    },
    name: "Banana A"
  },
  {
    entityId: {
      id: 2,
      version: 1
    },
    name: "Banana B"
  },
  {
    entityId: {
      id: 2,
      version: 2
    },
    name: "Banana B"
  },
]
```

How can I instead retrieve just the latest version of each Banana, so I only see V3 of Banana 1, and V2 of banana 2? I was able to find the query I need to get the id/version pairs:

```
select id, max(version) from action group by id
```

But I haven't yet figured out how to get the entire Banana entities. Should I instead be using the Criteria API? Is there a better way to version my entities? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for subquery. The idea is.

1. Find maximum version for Banana with some ID
2. Find whole Banana object with that ID and found version.

> ```
> select b from Banana b where b.version = 
>      (select max(bb.version) from Banana bb where bb.id = b.id)
> ```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!